# Laravel attach to model that doesn't exist

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have projects and plot types in my application.  A project can have many plot types.

The `project` table looks like this:

```
id    name
```

I also have a `project_plot_types` table that I want to enter information into.  This table looks like:

```
id    project_id    name
```

What kind of relationship do I need?  I do not have a `plot_types` table, so it's not a pivot relationship.

Can someone help?

Comment: Assuming that you will always have a plot type: `Project` [hasMany](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships#one-to-one) `Type`?  The opposite being: [belongsTo](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many)

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin the question is asking us to help identify the best relationship.

Answer (score 1):

That is a one-to-many relationship. Your Project model will have a projectPlotTypes function that returns like so:

```
return $this->hasMany('ProjectPlotType');
```

and conversely ProjectPlotType will have a Project function which returns:

```
return $this->belongsTo('Project');
```